# Why does "python" command start a new cmd window?

Tags: windows, command-line, python

I have Anaconda installed on Windows Server 2008 OS. Today, after an accidental system reboot, strange things happened. I started a CMD window and activated my anaconda python environment. Then when I typed 'python' to start the python interpreter, a new CMD window started, which is strange. Also, the 'pip list' command also started a new CMD window which disappeared immediately.

I don't know why. Could anyone give me some help?

[image: 'python' command start a new CMD window]

Comment: You might try to use System Restore and roll back to before this happened.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was caused by the executable being set to run as administrator in the compatability settings.

To fix this:

- Right-click on Python.exe
- Click *Properties* → *Compatibility*
- Uncheck *Run this program as an administrator*

Comment: Could you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1574514/edit) and expand upon your answer as it's not terribly clear. You mean right clicking on the file to obtain its properties?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when a reboot happens through power-failure or other unplanned crashes
is unpredictable and sometimes very hard to analyze.

The easiest solution is to use System Restore to roll back to before this happened,
to restore Windows to its previous working condition.